# How to use method oveloading in codeigniter models

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, model, overloading

I want to create overload methods in Codeigniter's model. I know method overloading is not supported in php like JAVA. So i Want to know which one is best way to do this from following two or please suggest if any other right way

```
function mymethod($p1 = null, $p2 = null){
   if (isset($p1)){
      echo "My method has 1st parameter<br>";
   }
   if (isset($p2)){
      echo "My method has 2nd parameter also";
   }
   rest code..
}
```

OR

```
public function __call($m , $p)
{
    switch($m)
    {
        case "mymethod":
            $count = count($p);
            switch($count)
            {
                case "0":
                    return "You are passing 0 argument";
                    break;
                case "1":
                    return "You are passing 1 argument";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    return "You are passing 2 parameter";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    return "You are passing 3 parameter";
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new exception("Bad argument");
            }
        default:
            throw new exception("Function $m does not exists ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In method overloading

1.) The number of parameters is different for the methods.
2.) The parameter types are different (like 
changing a parameter that was a float to an int).

above are the condition for method overloading

```
function mymethod($p1 = null, $p2 = null, $p3 = null){
   if (isset($p1)){
      echo "My method has 1st parameter<br>";
   }
   if (isset($p2)){
      echo "My method has 2nd parameter also";
   }
   rest code..
}
```